# ListView in Fragment - onItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview, fragment, onitemclicklistener

I have this Fragment: http://pastebin.com/zj5DLpwX
But my onItemClickListener is not working, it doesnt open the DetailActivity...
I just added the xml layouts, do you need some code?
Any ideas?

fragment_v:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>`
```

list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <!-- Name Label -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textColor="#43bd00"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- Email label -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:textColor="#acacac" />

            <!-- Mobile number label -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mobile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Mobile: "
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>`
```

This is the Fragment Code

```
package com.tw.vp;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class VFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;


   // public VFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    //}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_v, container, false);
        ListView lv =(ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Log.d("Aufruf", "onItemClick");
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();


        return v;
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                        String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                        String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                        String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                        contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                    TAG_PHONE_MOBILE },
                    new int[] { R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: post your logcat.can you add DetailActivity in your mainifest file

Comment: What happens exactly? Does it crash or just doesnt do anything? [logcat if it crashes]. Also be more descriptive in your questions please.

Comment: @tom post your xml please

Comment: It does simply nothing... Logcat says noting. Even if I add a log entry to the onItemClick it does noting... Manifest: <activity android:name=".DetailActivity"></activity>

Comment: @varunkr which xml layout?

Comment: @tom xml of the listView item

Comment: added some xml layouts

Comment: could you post your adapter code

Comment: @DineshBob here you go: http://pastebin.com/XeJJUnY3

Comment: thats not the listview adapter code.

Comment: @tom Check my answer below.

Comment: @DineshBob all adapter stuff is in the FragmentClass in the first post: http://pastebin.com/zj5DLpwX

Comment: no. i dont see any adapter in your code. you have to set a adapter to the listview. lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter());

Comment: @DineshBob in the end of VFragment there is:  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
...
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

Comment: sorry. didnt expect it inside AsyncTask. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ListFragment` then you can simply use its `override` method `onListItemClick()`.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

     // Your Stuff Goes Here
}
```

And also add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in root layout of list element.

Comment: now i get this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tomwellmann.vertretungsplan/com.tomwellmann.vertretungsplan.DetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Check in your `Detail Activity` their is null string while you getting data using `getStringExtra`.

Comment: Reason for `Down Vote` ? The problem of `Click Listener` is solved by this. He got Errors in other code stuff. Shoot your `Down Vote` reason here @DownVoter.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to your LinearLayout in the list_item xml

Comment: @tom did you try this ?

Comment: @tom if it works do consider upvoting/accepting ti. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

**Change below code from your code :-**

```
ListView lv;

//code to get the listView instance using findViewByID etc

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Toast.makeText(EnclosingActivity.this, "Clicking me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: okay, it changed the "onItemClickListener" to "lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()" and doesnt work... no toast appears

Comment: I am using Fragments